# Get all text from another C# winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, ui-automation, findwindowex

I'm trying to write an C# application to get **all** Text from another C# winform application. The text that I want to get is Button's text, Textbox's text content, Lable's text, etc. I have tried many different ways such as using UIAutomation, FindWindowEx but still not successful.
Could someone please show me a sample C# code to do that jobs?

Comment: uiautomation is the way to go

Comment: @pm100, how to list all component with UIAutomation?

Comment: What have you tested, and what doesn't work exactly?
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve